# Power supply for Precision Current Source for Medical Instrument

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, noise, emc, ldo

I am trying to implement power supply for constant current source(LM334) for medical application. I have 24V,3A SMPS to generate required output (38V) to operate [LM334](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm334) Constant current source of 10mA.

LM334 is followed by I/V converter and OP-amps and then ADC.
[image: datasheet]
[image: schematics]

Considering fact that LDO generate less noise than switching converter and LM334 has less error at higher operating voltage, I have come up with 2 schemes as mentioned below:

Scheme 1:
[image: Scheme1]

Scheme 2:

[image: scheme2]
**Which is better option ( in terms of noise , since signal strength is very less )to generate 38V for LM334 ?** Please someone guide.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Define "better".  Do you mean cheaper? Lower noise? Smallest PCB space? Efficiency? Heat dissipated? Also consider LM317 instead of 7805, if noise is an issue.

Comment: Better in terms of noise .. Since it is supply to signal conditioning circuit.

Comment: could do with a big electrolytic across that zener for noise if you want to use a 7805!

Comment: @Neil_UK ,Using LDO along with zener is better than boost converter ?

Comment: you need to define what 'noise' is before we start trying to compare LDO apples with boost converter orange giraffes. I'm not so sure the quest for MOAR POWA on the 334 is warranted. Some of its specs might be better at high voltage, but low dissipation often makes things better in other ways. I think you need to get back to the current specs you're trying to achieve, spectral noise density in differenet bands, and start again. In my experience, relying on the PSRR of something like a 334 is usually very good, as long as you have a 'king big electrolytic upstream to take out the HF rail noise.

Comment: Noise i am afraid of is, switching noise from SMPS and boost converter ... since switching converters are efficient but will add switching noise to system .. So I come up with boost conv followed by LDO.